# How to serve Envoy metrics endpoint over TLS with Istio?

Tags: prometheus, istio, envoyproxy

When deploying Istio, port 15090 exposed by Envoy sidecar for Prometheus metrics is unencrypted by default. I want all metrics collection to be encrypted so was wondering if it was possible to have Envoy serve that port over TLS using the normal certificates distributed by Citadel?

I would then use the Prometheus `tls_config` stanza to configure TLS client side too.

Istio version: 1.4.5

Comment: Hi, according to this [github](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7352) issue there is a possibility to do that. Are You interested in built-in Prometheus with `mTLS` or with `prometheus-operator` befriended to istio with `mTLS`?

Comment: I've got that working, but it appears the Envoy sidecar doesn't treat traffic to its metrics endpoint in the same way - that is I can configure Prometheus to attempt to connect using TLS, but I can't configure Envoy to serve TLS on that specific port (15090)

Comment: in the deployment.yaml  : did you define ```containerPort:9090``` ? did you put the special istio+promethous annotations  ?
```prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
     prometheus.istio.io/merge-metrics: "false"
     metircs_path....
     metrics_port...
```
another option: ignore istio's mTLS and bypass it directly into the pod by adding a pod annotation like : ```traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeInboundPorts: "9090"``` and then proceed with std Prometheous with the cert file and other TLS params.